# Javascript breaks when switching vue route

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm currently having the problem that the javascript related features in my component files breaks when switching to another route in VueJS.

In my Home.vue file, there is a revolution slider system and typed text that were included in the template I purchased. I am trying to implement Vue Router into the template. The template file has all the scripts that require to be included and the  is in the content area of the template.

When I switch to some other route and switch back to the Home.vue route, all the javascript related features are broken. The revolution slider doesnt show and the typed text doesnt change anymore. Im assuming that this is because the Home.vue doesnt use the scripts anymore. What's the most optimal way to fix this? Is there some way to like reload the scripts when switching routes?

Im also using Laravel as backend framework.

Comment: You may want to post the errors you are getting, preferably from your console.

Comment: an infinite loop of this: https://gyazo.com/259e8423db5db32185d3e1635532eab4